# What is exactly meaning of The notion of Sample path and Stochastic Process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-functions

I am wondering what Stochastic Process is exactly meaning.

---

Let me talk about what I understood.

[image]

I will give an example.

$\Omega_i$ is noise of my robot's circuit on July the $i$-th day.

The first graph is noise of my robot's circuit up to time t on July the $1$st day.

The second graph is noise of my robot's circuit up to time t on July the $2$st day.

The third graph is noise of my robot's circuit up to time t on July the $3$st day.

The fourth graph is noise of my robot's circuit up to time t on July the $4$st day.

The fifth graph is noise of my robot's circuit up to time t on July the $5$st day.

Each graphs are called Sample Function, Realization or Sample path.

Stochastic Process is first graph + $\cdots$ + fifth graph.

Is it right?

Comment: Your description of the graphs is correct, but the graphs themselves do not make a stochastic process, because there is a dependence on the "randomization variable" which is held constant in those graphs.

Comment: Hmm, can I ask which is random(stochastic) process in the above picture?

Comment: You can't see a stochastic process in any picture. It's an abstract kind of object.

Comment: Okay, thank you~ I will think more with reference to your comments.

Comment: Actually, sorry, I think I misunderstood. If each graph is a sample path, then the stochastic process is the collection of all possible graphs, equipped with whatever distribution is on the paths.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34341/discussion-between-danny-kim-and-ian).